# how to access multiple checkboxes names while checkbox name is coming from database in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, checkbox

Below code is showing some data from database, here in each row there is a checkbox having name of primaryid from database ..and when user click less than then 5 checkboxes a alert appear as show all the code is working .but

Here I want that when user click 5 checkboxes i want the unique name of 5 checkboxes select and on submit button click and i want to do some php code with these 5 unique ids.

```
$sql="some sql";
$result = mysqli_query($mysql,$sql);

while($res1=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {


                    ?>
                                <tr>

                                <td>

                                <input type="checkbox" name="studentid"  value="<?php echo $res1['leadID']?>" ></td>


                <td>some stuff here </td>
                              </tr>
                    <?php }
                                ?>     

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn newcol1" id="submit2"  onClick="checkboxes();">


                 <script>
     function checkboxes()
      {

       var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
        count = 0;

        for (var i=0; i<inputElems.length; i++) {       
           if (inputElems[i].type == "checkbox" && inputElems[i].checked == true){
              count++;

           }

        }
        if(count < 5){
                  alert ("Select at least 5 leads");
                  }




  } </script>
```

Comment: Structure your code please, it's all over the place

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want, but here I have made it so the checkboxes() function adds all the unique IDs to an array and then if more than 5 checkboxes have been clicked, POST them to the current page and you can access the IDs in PHP.

```
function checkboxes(){
    var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    count = 0;

    var ids = []
    for (var i=0; i<inputElems.length; i++) {       
        if (inputElems[i].type == "checkbox" && inputElems[i].checked == true){
            ids.push(inputElems[i].getAttribute("value"));
            count++;
        }
    }

    if(count < 5){
        alert ("Select at least 5 leads");
    }
    else{
        //more than 5 checkboxes selected
        post(window.location.href, {ids: ids});
    }
}

function post(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.

    // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
    // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);

    for(var key in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
         }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```